# Клиент новостей для блога

Tags: c#, .net

Ребят, хотел бы кое-что у вас спросить.. 
Хотел бы сделать клиент новостей для блога(с#). Опишу понятнее: есть интерфейс, там (хотя бы для начала) должны отображаться записи с блога. 
Можете подсказать с чего начать и что я должен знать?

Comment: Вот бы все ТЗ так понятно объяснялись бы! Вам надо, для начала, научиться писать развернутые ответы, потому что на ваш вопрос можно дать ответ, выдержанный в таком же стиле, типа "Создаёте проект, ...берёте коннектор к базе данных, придумываете SQL запрос, который будет выбирать данные из таблицы. Ну и потом просто-напросто набрасываете код, который данные из таблицы отображает на этом самом интерфейсе".

Comment: @void вот впринципе я это и хотел увидеть. Просто я не знаю с чего стартовать.    
Вы можете подсказать буквально пару книг\статей?   
Буду благодарен

Comment: Хороший список книг есть тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/198316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Sin2p](/users/19421/sin2p) Я не буду приводить ссылок, так как нет конкретной (адекватной) статьи, посвященной такой конкретной задаче. Даже если и есть, то цена ей грош, если ее оценивать по шкале полезности на данный момент для вас. И вот почему:

Вот, например, "отображаться записи с блога" - что мы здесь подразумеваем? У вас есть доступ к базе данных, где хранятся записи блога? Есть? Ок, учим C#, особенно те главы, которые объясняют, как работать с базами. К моменту прочтения *той* главы у вас **уже** будет большое представление о том, как необходимое **всё** *остальное* работает. При условии, что не будете просто эти предыдущие главы перелистывать.

Нет доступа и надо брать записи из RSS? Ок, здесь уже дело в другом..

Или не база и не RSS? Ну тогда вообще...

И вообще, вы WinForms или WPF будете использовать? Или это Web-аппликация?

Дело в том, что **не надо на C# (как и на любом другом) пытаться решить конкретную задачу, не зная базиса**.

*Здесь, на сайте, - по тэгам и с помощью поиска, вы найдете много ответов с рекомендациями ресурсов по изучению C# (в том числе и моих).*

Начинайте учить C# с нуля и следуйте по главам. Иначе все ваши вопросы (от непонимания базиса) будут выглядеть как "Как сделать, чтобы мой сайт выглядел бы пи*дато?" с ответами вроде "В углу программы нажмите на кнопку 'Сделать пи*дато'".

Иного пути нет и не может быть. Это аксиома.

Comment: Спасибо, я вас понял
Будем постигать истины с#

Comment: Учите. Не пожалеете. Самое главное, не сдавайтесь. А через полгода упорного изучения зайдите на ссылку этой страницы - это будет огромным стимулом для дальнейшего саморазвития в плане программирования.

Answer (score 2):

Если совсем для начала - сделайте на стороне клиента парсер страниц блога. Используйте любую из кучи библиотек (рекомендую [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)) для парсинга и выводите в клиентском приложении как необходимо.

А вообще - необходим API этого блога для нормальной работы.